# Modelling uncertainties in sampling

Tags: probability, sampling, simulation

I am seeking to complete/perfect a simulation program in Excel that models the following:

**Step 1**

Sample N items where the probability p of any item being in one of two states. It is handy to depict these two states with a 1 and a 0, respectively, so one can use Boolean algebra. P(1)=p. P(0) =1-p

So far so good: I have coded for each successive sample (1 to N) in my simulation with:

```
=IF(RAND()<”p”,1,0)
```

and that produces results with means and standard deviations that conform very closely to what binomial theory predicts

$σ =(p(1-p)/N)^{0.5}$

as I vary values for p in the range 0% to 100%.

I know, that < should be ≤ , but the difference is inconsequential with Excel generating random numbers between 0 to 1 to 10 decimal places.

**Step 2**

Model the uncertainty in my example that categorizations of all the above sampled items as a 1 or a 0 cannot be made with 100% reliability. The probability that the sampler can correctly identify whether the sampled item is actually a 1 is only c (the probability of mis-categorization to a 0 is thus 1-c), and the probability that the sampler can correctly identify that a sampled item is actually a 0 is also c (the probability of mis-categorization to a 1 is thus also 1-c).

My overall objective is to determine the overall standard deviation of possible outcomes with variability due both to sampling, and due to uncertainties in assessing the sampled items.

```
=IF(RAND()<c,“sampled”,BITXOR(“sampled”,1)
```

I’m using Excel’s BITXOR function with the dummy variable fixed at 1 to synthesise the logical NOT function because Excel does not have a Boolean NOT function.

**Results**

With hundreds and thousands of samplings and determinations in my simulations, the variances are also plausible for the uncertain determinations (i.e. judgments whether 1 or 0 is applicable to the sampled items). However, in every simulation run, with various different levels of p and c as inputs, the determined average value of p (let’s call it p’) is closer to 50% than was p. This does not make sense to me. While I can appreciate that some adjustment in outcome must occur to reflect the imprecise determinations, my model’s skew seems to lack a symmetry I would expect.

While I have described the status of 1 or 0 as being “actualities” versus imprecise determinations/judgments in the above, the status of 1 or 0 could just as easily be an imprecise  perception in both cases (i.e. as if the truth cannot ever be know with certainty and we are comparing opinions/judgements), with my model modelling the extent of agreement, as well as (mean) values for p and p’. Under these latter circumstances, I can’t see why the mean value of p’ should necessarily be closer to 50% than the mean value for p.

Am I right or what am I missing? Is there more than one mathematical solution to my problem that I am not including in my simulation, or is there something else wrong in my modelling.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like p is an input (a constant), and your estimate of p (the average of the samples, ignoring the existence of c) is called p'. Since c is just adding noise to your data, it is no surprise that the average of the data is moved towards 50%. Imagine if c=1/2, then all your samples would be pure noise and p' would be exactly 50% regardless of p.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Yes, at c=50% p' is always 50% because its determination is then independent of p. My simulation shows that case well graphically with a nice-looking normal distribution histogram around 50%. But c is a measure of agreement and does relate p' with p.  For example, with c =100% and p =20%, p'=20% as well. What I don't understand is why p' is always biasing towards 50% rather than p ever doing so, when my model simply reflects two different sets of determinations, rather than one second-guessing the other. That's why I'm concerned about asymmetry with my model eg @ c=75% and p=20%.

Comment: Ah, this makes it more clear what your'e asking. Yes, it could seem like the situation is symmetric between p and p', because applying the mis-categorization twice should get you back to the correct categorization.  But this would only be the case if the second re-categorization could know to apply itself exactly to the mis-categorized cases, which is not how it worked the first time, so there is no symmetry.

Comment: Think of the mis-categorization like this:  With probability 2(1-c), the categorization is completely randomized (to 50/50).  This is the same as your model, because half the time, the randomized category would be correct, so it would only become incorrect (1-c) of the time.  Now you have a system where sometimes you observe the correct category, and sometimes you flip a coin.  So your final statistics p' are a weighted average of p and 50%.  The value of c controls this weighted average.  So p' is closer to 50% than p is.

Comment: Thanks again, Matt.

Comment: 50:50 is a special case that my model needs to accommodate but this is not really my specific interest which involves wide ranges for p <50%  and c >50%. I’m switching now to upper case for clarity.
I think I have figured out how to refine my model (correctly) to provide the symmetry I was expecting.

Comment: There are really 3 different Ps:
• The actual value of P, which I’ll call P, which cannot be determined with certainty because no item in the sample can be correctly identified with certainty as having a 1 value or a 0 value.
• The value of P imperfectly estimated by the first assessor, which I’ll call P1.
• The value of P imperfectly estimated by the second assessor, which I’ll call P2.

Comment: My model can deal with relationships between P and P1, and between P and P2. For example, I can simply run my model twice and check for agreement and disagreement in assessments on an item-by-item basis. Those two relationships are the same, but are subject to random effects I model in individual imprecise determinations, averages and standard deviations of results.

Comment: Test results in the real world show values for P1 and P2 and the rate of agreement between the two assessors. That is the value of C.

There is another agreement variable in my model. That is the accuracy rate that I call A. It is the measure of the extent to which an assessor’s estimations agree with actuality (rather than with the other assessors’ determinations that are also imperfect).

Comment: I can now use those real-world results to figure out what the value of P is from a look-up table I have generated from my simulation model. I can also model the relationship between A and C and also include corresponding values for them my look-up table.

As previously discussed, the value of P1 tends to skew towards 50% (i.e. higher in my area of interest) versus any value of P below 50%. This is because false positives exceed false negatives in that region.

Comment: Both P1 and P2 have the same skew so there is symmetry between those values and between the two assessors that have estimated those P1 and P2 values. The asymmetry is only between an assessor (i.e. in its skewed perception of P with P1 or P2 ) and the reality in P.